# staging server shared databse with main production server

Tags: database, web-deployment, production, staging

in my workplace we have setup a django web app on staging server running frontend and on production server running frontend , the frontend is a UI for deploying projects . however recently I was pointed out that staging server should not be using the production database. That makes complete sense. However the staging server beside just for testing the changes made also serves as a failsafe as runs on docker based apache server and docker runs on different machine. so if something is wrong we are able the developers are able to make use of staging server for publishing there softwares meanwhile my team fixes the production server. But the frontend of staging server as well is connected to same database as the production (as it is required for developers to be able to use staging server as failsafe)

So my question is does sharing database between web apps running on staging and production can cause an issue ? how it should be handled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With my personal experience, if your database host is powerful enough, you should be fine. I've had zero problems doing what you mentioned above. People quite possibly consider it a security concern since there will be more bugs/exploits in your staging web app where an attacker could access your database and affect your production web app. But that's only a worst case scenario.

Comment: What is recommended approach otherwise?

Comment: Use the same database host, but make a separate database.